# How to get all the data from the form on the site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

the site does not have a public api, there is a form on the site with a schedule, is it possible to write a script that will collect data from this form on demand?

This site: https://www.altstu.ru/main/schedule/

This is actually a database request of this form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_faculty').change(function () {
        var facultyId = $('#id_faculty').val();
        $('#submit').after('<img id="loading" src="/media/static/js/lytebox/images/loading.gif" alt="loading..." style="vertical-align: middle" />');
        $.getJSON('/main/schedule/ws/group/', {f: facultyId},
            function(data) {
                if ($.isArray(data)) {
                    $('#id_group').children().remove();
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $('#id_group').append('<option value="' + item['id'] + '">' + item['name'] + '</option>');
                    });
                }
                else { alert(data); }
                $('#loading').remove();
            }
        );
    })
})
```

Comment: So you want other website data in your website?

Comment: Hi, this is not my site, I would like to receive data from it for example in json